# Is it possible to render different parts/tabs of a template/page asynchronously with Django only?

Tags: django, django-templates

One of my pages has 4 tabs in it. Some tabs require longer backend processing, but I don't want the page to wait for each tab, instead I want each tab to be displayed as soon as it is ready. So far I used **rest api** for each tab and then created the whole tab in JS. But I like using Django templates much better.

Is there a way to have to it so that I can still create each tab in Django templates?

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    {% include 'my_project/tab1.html' %}
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
    {% include 'my_project/tab2.html' %}
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
    {% include 'my_project/tab3.html'%}
</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
    {% include 'my_project/tab4.html'%}
</div>
```

I have single URL, I want this URL to invoke 4 backend views handler to render each of the tab htmls.

Comment: AJAX+REST is a correct approach. If you want to use templates for async parts - try returning rendered (in terms of django) templates as a response to REST calls. Moving towards frontend frameworks like VUE or React is not a bad choice as well.

Answer (score 2):

Django

```
def get_tab1(request) # called by get_tab1 in urls.py
    ....
    return render(request,  "tab1.html", {<whatever data>})
```

Template

```
<div id = tab1></div>
<div id = tab2></div>
etc.
```

Also have HTML template for each tab.

JS 
(Ajax here is jQuery. Do however JS does ajax for plain JS)

```
// get tab html and insert it in page
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_tab1/", 
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
      document.getElementById("tab1").innerHTML = data;
    }
    ,error: function() {
    } 
 });
```

You may run into CSRF issue with this code. I provide CSRF token with every post request, but you can also make the view @csrf_exempt. Or make it GET.